# Send array via Ajax with string index

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I try to post an array with string index via Ajax, no data will be transferred.
Please let me know the reason.

```
                         var coord=new Array;
                   coord["x"]=12;
                   coord["y"]=12;
                   coord["w"]=44;
                   coord["h"]=66;
                 console.log(coord);              
var parameter={coord:coord};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: parameter,
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                url:'http://localhost/server/main/crop_image',
                success: function(response) {

                },
                error: function() {

                },
                complete: function() {

                }
            });
```

Comment: array with string index its not array :-) its simply object, anyway try use `data: JSON.stringify(parameter)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding values to your array using string, this adds properties to your array object, not actual array values.

You have two choices:

1. Either use object `{}` instead of `new Array`, or
2. Use `coord.push(12); coord.push(42);` etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line  `var coord = new Array;`  to `var coord = {}`   (object not Array)

Arrays in javascript are objects so you can do `coord["x"] = "bla bla"`  (same as `coord.x = "bla bla"`) but in JSON arrays are lists of objects, so jQuery ignores those non-list properties of the array objects when translating the data to JSON.

By changing coord to be an object and not Array jQuery will translate it to JSON object which works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var parameter={coord:coord.join()};
```

on client you will get csv value which you can again convert it into array depending on server side language

**PHP**

```
 $pizza  = "piece1,piece2,piece3";
 $pieces = explode(",", $pizza);
 echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
 echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

**JAVA**

```
 String[] ary = "piece1,piece2,piece3".split(",");
```